# Espaço entre linhas HTML

Tags: html, css

Olá estou com um problema com uma assinatura na empresa aonde eu trabalho, tive que adicionar alguns ícones e deixar mais bonito, até ai tudo ok, porem ficou um espaço entre as linhas que eu não consigo retirar, alguém poderia me ajudar pois não sou muito bom com HTML.

```html
<p class=MsoNormal>Atenciosamente,</p>
<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
</div>
<table width="450" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100"><img src="http://www.designbento.com.br/apoio/ecoplan/ass-ecoplan.gif" alt="Ecoplan - aÃ§os especiais" border="0" /></td>
<td width="279" valign="bottom" style="margin-right: 30px;">
<p style="font-family: Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; font-size: 17px;"><b>Nome do funcionário </b>
    <HR  ALIGN=RIGHT NOSHADE COLOR=#ffffff >
  <img src="https://images.assetsdelivery.com/compings_v2/koblizeek/koblizeek1901/koblizeek190100017.jpg" width="17" height="17"  /><span style="font-size: 12px;">Cargo do funcionario
  <p style="font-family: Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; font-size: 12px;"p>
  <img src="http://www.dunfermlinesound.org.uk/webs/107/images/WS1831923.png" width="15" height="15" />+ramal e numero da empresa
  <HR  ALIGN=RIGHT NOSHADE COLOR=RED >
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/acosecoplan/"><img src="https://iconsplace.com/wp-content/uploads/_icons/ff0000/256/png/facebook-2-icon-14-256.png" width="20" height="20" /></a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/acosecoplan"><img src="https://icon-library.net/images/linkedin-image-icon/linkedin-image-icon-12.jpg" width="20" height="20" /></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/acosecoplan/"><img src=https://iconsplace.com/wp-content/uploads/_icons/ff0000/256/png/instagram-2-icon-14-256.png" width="20" height="20" /></a>
<br><a class="redtext" style="text-decoration:none" title="acesse nosso site" href="http://www.acosecoplan.com.br">www.acosecoplan.com.br</a></p></br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Entre quais linhas exatamente?

Comment: como está o arquivo de css que faz referencia a essa parte?

Comment: Entre as linhas que fica o nome do funcionario, e o cargo.

Answer (score 1):

Adicione a propriedade `style="margin: 2px;` na sua *tag* `<hr>`. No caso, vai controlar a margem nas quatro direções (*top*, *right*, *bottom* e *left*), mas no seu caso já parece ser suficiente. Caso queira diminuir ainda mais o espaçamento, deixe um valor menor ainda. **Observação**: havia uma tag `</div>` isolada no começo do código que a removi. Veja se assim resolve.

```html
<p class=MsoNormal>Atenciosamente,</p>
<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

<table width="450" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td width="100"><img src="http://www.designbento.com.br/apoio/ecoplan/ass-ecoplan.gif" alt="Ecoplan - aÃ§os especiais" border="0" /></td>
  <td width="279" valign="bottom" style="margin-right: 30px;">
    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; font-size: 17px;"><b>Nome do funcionário </b></p>
    
    <hr  align=RIGHT noshade="" color="#ffffff" style="margin: 2px;" >

  <img src="https://images.assetsdelivery.com/compings_v2/koblizeek/koblizeek1901/koblizeek190100017.jpg" width="17" height="17"  /><span style="font-size: 12px;">Cargo do funcionario
  <p style="font-family: Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; font-size: 12px;"p>
  <img src="http://www.dunfermlinesound.org.uk/webs/107/images/WS1831923.png" width="15" height="15" />+ramal e numero da empresa
  <HR  ALIGN=RIGHT NOSHADE COLOR=RED >
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/acosecoplan/"><img src="https://iconsplace.com/wp-content/uploads/_icons/ff0000/256/png/facebook-2-icon-14-256.png" width="20" height="20" /></a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/acosecoplan"><img src="https://icon-library.net/images/linkedin-image-icon/linkedin-image-icon-12.jpg" width="20" height="20" /></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/acosecoplan/"><img src=https://iconsplace.com/wp-content/uploads/_icons/ff0000/256/png/instagram-2-icon-14-256.png" width="20" height="20" /></a>
<br><a class="redtext" style="text-decoration:none" title="acesse nosso site" href="http://www.acosecoplan.com.br">www.acosecoplan.com.br</a></p></br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda de verdade! me ajudou muito...

Comment: Legal, se puder aceitar a resposta, veja o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).